# How do I check if my nVidia GPU supports VDPAU?

Tags: nvidia, vdpau

MPlayer does not work if I try to make it use VDPAU. How do I check if my card supports it and what else do I need to install to enable it?

Comment: the answer on the other question does not satisfy you? ;)

Comment: @brunopereira81 I posted this question before your answer, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much any card after the 8000 series GPU's are supported. Make sure you have the nVidia proprietary driver installed, as vdpau doesn't not work with the nouveau driver.

Here's a table of nVidia GPU's supporting vdpau: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/VDPAU#Supported_Cards

Also, make sure that the package `vdpau-va-driver` is installed. You can then run `vainfo` to see if your card is supported.

Comment: As far as I know, `vainfo` shows info about VAAPI, an entire different video acceleration API for AMD/Intel video cards. The right command for NVidia VDPAU info is `vdpauinfo`